# Memory leak in DateFormatter

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, dateformatter

I often use `DateFormatter` in the code and did not see any problems, but then I decided to test one class for a lot number of iterations - I noticed a huge memory leak.

The reason for the leak was `DateFormatter`.

Simple code:

```
var dateFormatter:DateFormatter
dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let date : Date = Date()
for _ in 1...100000000 {
    _ = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

No leaks. **5.9 MB** per process all run time.

But when I use `dateFormat`:

```
var dateFormatter:DateFormatter
dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let date : Date = Date()
dateFormatter!.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"
for _ in 1...100000000 {
    _ = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Use memory up **4 GB** at the end of run time.

If I use:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
```

No Leaks.

If I use:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHH"
```

Leaks.

Comment: The second problem was the time of execution.
I had to use  *NSDate (). TimeIntervalSince1970*

Comment: Used up memory and a leak are fundamentally different things.

Comment: Are you testing this in a playground?

Comment: Profile mark this is as memory leak) Test like console app)

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you're creating zero-length strings. Modify your code to print them out; you don't see anything in the log. Try assigning the output of the date formatter to a variable and checking its value by placing a breakpoint in the loop; the value is always an empty string. This would explain why the memory usage remains as low as it does.

In your second example, you *are* creating strings, per the date format. As before, check the value from the date formatter and you'll see. This explains why you're rapidly exhausting your physical RAM: You're creating 100 million non-empty strings within that loop.

This isn't a best practice, even in the first example. Chances are that, if you really need 100 million strings, you do something with them, like place them in an array instantiated elsewhere, or whatnot. You don't want to let them accumulate inside that humongous loop.

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
    let date = Date()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"

    for _ in 1...100000000 {
        autoreleasepool(invoking: { () -> () in
            let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            print("\(string)")
        })
    }
```

Note that I'm making use of an *autoreleasepool* closure within the loop. This ensures that the string I create in each pass of the loop is deallocated before the next iteration. Within that closure, you can do whatever you want with that string. You can create any number of values within it, and they'll all be deallocated before the next iteration of the loop. On my machine, everything purrs along at a constant 16.2 MB of memory consumed. Your mileage may vary.

Best wishes to you in your endeavors.

Comment: Ok) first example - my fault)) But when use dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd" without autoreleasepool - no leaks when use "yyyyMMddHH" - huge memory use or leaks (profile mark this is as leaks)

Comment: You're asking me to comment on the internals of DateFormatter. I can't explain its behavior. But in any case, if you're instantiating objects in a loop, you should do so in an autoreleasepool closure to ensure they're released before the next iteration.